# Confusion over OCSP support from a web-site? Openssl vs Broweser Information? Which one to believe?

Tags: networking, ssl, openssl

I am looking at a website in Google Chrome, according to an article that I read online in order to check if a website supports OCSF you can look at the Certificates>Details>Extensions and then see if it has smth like http://ocsp.blla.blla.blla ...

So I am looking to the website that I am interested to know if it supports OCSP, and I am looking at the certificates extensions and I see the link and the issuer for OCSP.

But when I am testing for OCSP using OpenSSL, with the following line:

```
openssl s_client -connect thewebIwantToLookat.com:443 -tls1 -tlsextdebug -status
```

It is returning:

```
OCSP response: no response sent
```

Meaning there is no OCSP support.

So now which one should I believe, this should be deterministic, right?

Comment: Whether an HTTPS or other TLS server supports OCSP _stapling_ (i.e. OCSP _within TLS_) is entirely separate from whether the _CA_ supports OCSP (i.e. OCSP _to_ the CA or its delegate). Which one do you want to know?

Comment: I want to know if the TLS server of that particular site so port :443 is using OCSP

Comment: TLS doesn't use the actual protocol OCSP because TLS can't send an OCSP request and get a response to it. TLS _can_ use (two forms of) what is officially called status_request and widely nicknamed OCSP stapling, which re-uses an OCSP response previously obtained by the server; [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCSP_stapling). That's what `openssl s_client -status` does.